# Weird box chart shape in Teechart

Tags: c#, teechart

I'm using Teechart(.Net 2009) in a project, and I found something weird happening when I draw a box with specific double points.

This is my xaml code to reproduce the problem.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="chartHost"/>
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="chartHost2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the behind code for the above xaml file.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
    InitializeComponent();

        SetChart(new[] { 0.5685, 0.7141, 0.7301, 0.748, 0.7847, 1.2127 }, chartHost);
        SetChart(new[] { 0.5686, 0.7141, 0.7301, 0.748, 0.7847, 1.2127 }, chartHost2);
    }

    private void SetChart(double[] values, WindowsFormsHost host)
    {
        var chart = new TChart();
        var box = new Box(chart.Chart);
        box.Add(values);
        box.ExtrOut.HorizSize = 0;
        box.ExtrOut.VertSize = 0;
        box.MildOut.HorizSize = 0;
        box.MildOut.VertSize = 0;

        chart.Axes.Left.Maximum = 1.2;
        chart.Axes.Left.Minimum = 0.5;

        host.Child = chart;
    }
}
```

The result looks like this. (Please click the link to see the captured image. I currently cannot attach image due to the reputation limit.)

http://www.flickr.com/photos/99238307@N06/9341426974/

Surprisingly, the only difference between two charts is that the first double value of each chart's data. The first double value of the left looks-ok-chart is 0.5685 and another one uses 0.5686 which sounds not that big difference. The 0.0001 made the right chart weird. I didn't try to use UseCustomValues property of the Box series and I don't want to use that.

Anybody knows how to draw the chart correctly with both two data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as designed. The solution here is using custom values. You can see the difference by dropping *ListBox* and *TChart* components in a *Form* and using this code:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  InitializeChart();
}

private void InitializeChart()
{
  bool automatic = true;

  SetChart(new[] { 0.5685, 0.7141, 0.7301, 0.748, 0.7847, 1.2127 }, automatic);
  SetChart(new[] { 0.5686, 0.7141, 0.7301, 0.748, 0.7847, 1.2127 }, automatic);

  tChart1.Axes.Left.SetMinMax(0.55, 1.25);
}

private void SetChart(double[] values, bool auto)
{
  var box = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Box(tChart1.Chart);
  box.Add(tChart1.Series.Count, values);

  if (auto)
  {
    box.ReconstructFromData();

    listBox1.Items.Add("Series: " + box.Title.ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add("Median: " + box.Median.ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add("Quartile1: " + box.Quartile1.ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add("Quartile3: " + box.Quartile3.ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add("InnerFence1: " + box.InnerFence1.ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add("InnerFence3: " + box.InnerFence3.ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add("OuterFence1: " + box.OuterFence1.ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add("OuterFence3: " + box.OuterFence3.ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add("AdjacentPoint1: " + box.AdjacentPoint1.ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add("AdjacentPoint3: " + box.AdjacentPoint3.ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add("-------------------------");
  }
  else
  {
    box.UseCustomValues = !auto;

    box.Median = 0.73905;
    box.OuterFence1 = 0.0357;
    box.OuterFence3 = 1.5337;

    box.InnerFence1 = 0.3567;
    box.InnerFence3 = 1.2127;

    box.Quartile1 = 0.6777;
    box.Quartile3 = 0.8917;

    box.AdjacentPoint1 = box.YValues[0];
    box.AdjacentPoint3 = 1.2127;

    box.Median = 0.73905;
  }
}
```

With *automatic* variable being *true* you'll see automatically calculated values as in this image:

[image]

Setting it to *false* it will use manual custom values. To see the difference you should have a look at how *ReconstructFromData()* method is implemented (you can check it with a reflector tool):

```
/// <summary>
/// Reconstructs the box plot from series data
/// </summary>
public void ReconstructFromData()
{
  int N = SampleValues.Count;
  if (N > 0)
  {
    double InvN = 1.0 / N;
    /* calculate median */
    int med = N / 2;
    if ((N % 2) == 0) median = 0.5 * (SampleValues[med - 1] + SampleValues[med]);
    else median = SampleValues[med];

    /* calculate Q1 && Q3 */
            quartile1 = N > 1 ? Percentile(SampleValues, 0.25) : SampleValues[0];
            quartile3 = N > 1 ? Percentile(SampleValues, 0.75) : SampleValues[0];

    /* calculate IQR */
    double iqr = quartile3 - quartile1;
    innerFence1 = quartile1 - whiskerLength * iqr;
    innerFence3 = quartile3 + whiskerLength * iqr;

    /* find adjacent points */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= med; i++) if (SampleValues[i] > innerFence1) break;
    adjacentPoint1 = SampleValues[i];

    for (i = med; i < N; i++) if (SampleValues[i] > innerFence3) break;
    adjacentPoint3 = SampleValues[i - 1];

    /* calculate outer fences */
    outerFence1 = quartile1 - 2 * whiskerLength * iqr;
    outerFence3 = quartile3 + 2 * whiskerLength * iqr;
  }
}
```

What makes a difference here is *adjacentPoint3*. In the first box-plot, *innerFence3* coincides with the last value in the series while in the second box-plot it's slightly smaller. Therefore, this code:

```
for (i = med; i < N; i++) if (SampleValues[i] > innerFence3) break;
adjacentPoint3 = SampleValues[i - 1];
```

breaks one step before than in the first series and penultimate value is being used instead of the last. Hence the difference in *AdjacentPoint3* and what's being painted.

To get data calculated automatically you can do something like this:

```
box.ReconstructFromData();

box.UseCustomValues = true;

box.Median = box.Median;
box.OuterFence1 = box.OuterFence1;
box.OuterFence3 = box.OuterFence3;

box.InnerFence1 = box.InnerFence1;
box.InnerFence3 = box.InnerFence3;

box.Quartile1 = box.Quartile1;
box.Quartile3 = box.Quartile3;

box.AdjacentPoint1 = box.AdjacentPoint1;
box.AdjacentPoint3 = box.YValues[box.Count-1];

box.Median = box.Median;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to use the method _ReconstructFromData_, but it didn't work. 

box.ReconstructFromData();

I added this line at the end of the SetChart method. The result is same. :-(

Comment: @BruceYang after investigating the issue further we found this is not a bug. I corrected my answer above.